# How to contribute type with key in hibernate 5.3

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

In my application I want to register name for a custom type while declaring a custom dialect. I don't want to use @TypeDef annotation because I want to have different type mapped for tests loaded on startup than in concrete app. Prior to Hibernate 5.3 I would do something like

```
class TestCustomH2Dialect : PostgreSQL94Dialect() {
    init {
        this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "LONGVARCHAR")
    }

    override fun contributeTypes(typeContributions: TypeContributions, serviceRegistry: ServiceRegistry) {
        super.contributeTypes(typeContributions, serviceRegistry)
        typeContributions.contributeType(
                MyTestType(),
                MyClass::class.java.canonicalName,
                "MyTestType"
        )
    }

}
```

And then this declaration works

```
@Type(type = "MyTestType")
@Column(name = "test_type", nullable = false)
var testType: TestType,
```

In Hibernate 5.3 this contributeType method is deprecated and due to documentation one should use version with only BasicType as parameter. Problem is when I'm trying to use it my alias for type is not being recognized unless I put @TypeDef or write a full class path to @Type annotation. Is there some alternative?

Comment: Your `UserType` contribution should work without change until 6.0 when the entire type system will be revamped, and almost none of the old APIs will remain. Its deprication marking is merely a warning for the future. If it stopped working between 5.2 and 5.3, then you should file a regression bug.